# From a Ruby `Errno` object, is it possible to get OS error information?

Tags: ruby, tcp

I'm getting a Ruby error like this:

```
Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: can't assign requested address - connect(2)
```

I'd like to be able to query the `Errno` object to find out what IP and port is being illegally reused.

Is there any way to find this out? I'm afraid the answer is "no, the OS only provides Ruby with the error number and nothing more".

I've tried raising, rescuing and tinkering with an error object like this, and I don't see anything in its `.methods` output that seems relevant. `.methods(false)` is empty.

Comment: can you not retrieve the IP and port from the socket that caused the exception in the first place? Just a thought.

Comment: @JensTinfors - this was happening deep in a framework call, so I don't have access to that socket.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I found for you is that : http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Errno.html, which indicates it is a subclass of http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/SystemCallError.html, and I don't see anything like what you're asking for. Looks like the exception is not exhaustive enough.